# Issue with regex - Content-Disposition multiline

Tags: c#, regex

I have

```
^Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"(.+)\"[\r\n]+(.+?).\s
```

and i want to get out to match groups, name and content from the text:

```
    --xYzZY
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

    131 æøå

    Kjetil Ormestad Eid
    Webutvikler

http://www.hafslund.no
Skype: kjetileid
Mobil: 99 26 62 15
--xYzZY
```

like name = text and content: 131 æøå ..... 26 62 15

I have tried:
https://regex101.com/r/mX51ru/29

but its only able to get som text from the multiline match

Comment: is this thing you need ? https://regex101.com/r/mX51ru/30

Comment: i want to extract the name and the content in two groups, this only matches the Content-Disposition line

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0NNJMw/1

Comment: yes like this: https://regex101.com/r/0NNJMw/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the following *regex* ...

```
(?s)Content-Disposition:\sform-data;\sname="(.*?)"(.*?)--xYzZY
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JmhIoB/1/)**